# What is the difference between the Hashgraph and the Tangle from IOTA?

Tags: tangle

I know a little bit about **`IOTA`** (as little as what is contained in the Whitepaper).

I do not know much about `Hashgraph`. But it seems to have been inspired by **`IOTA`**.

What is the difference between the `Hashgraph` and the `Tangle` from **`IOTA`**?

What is the relation between `Hashgraph` and **`IOTA`**?

Comment: Not asking too much, but the advantages of each technology would be good. Moderation is free to edit my question if I find it too broad.

Comment: This is a very broad question. You should just google to get the basics about both technologies. After you did that, come back on here and ask educated and specific questions about the differences or relations at smaller areas of both technologies.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a complete answer, but here are a few points:

- IOTA is a cryptocurrency, whereas Hashgraph is an algorithm, i.e. there is no public ledger built on Hashgraph (yet)
- IOTA is open-source technology, whereas Hashgraph is patented Distributed Ledger Technology & not open-source (yet)
- In IOTA there is no absolute unique order of transactions (yet), whereas the Hashgraph algorithm allows to deterministically determine such an order in their system
- IOTA requires PoW, whereas Hashgraph does not

Here a link on Hashgraph:
https://youtu.be/pcToFASnyrc